# I want to to use the first 3 letters of a user entered string ex. "january" outcome:"jan"

Tags: java, string, joptionpane

The user enters a `JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter month").`

The outcome should only be 3 letters `"jan"`, `"feb"` or `"mar"`.

Comment: If my solution worked for you, can you vote it up and mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Use `inputString = inputString.substring(0, 3);`, where `inputString` is the month entered.

Comment: i would but i dont have 15 points myself so i cant vote yet sorry